# How do I plot arithmetic sum and natural log function in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot these two functions in matplotlib for 1 <= n <= 10000. I'm not very familiar with it, so I couldn't really figure out an effective way to do it. What do I need to write in order to plot and show the graphs of these two functions? I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service and "Somebody code this for me" is not a valid question. Please provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried so far based on your own research, and what _specific_ difficulties you run into

Answer (score 1):

The first function can be plotted as follows:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k = np.arange(1, 10001)
g = np.log(k)
f = g.cumsum()
plt.plot(k, f)
plt.show()
```

[image: sum of log(k)]

As mentioned in the comments, the second function can be plotted up till `k=170` via `np.log(scipy.special.factorial(k))`. For `k=171` the factorial is larger than the highest number that can be represented in 64-bit floating point.

To obtain values for larger `k`, pythons multiprecission math library `mpmath` can be used. mpmath is much slower than numpy, and doesn't operate on arrays, so it needs some conversions.

The following plot shows the difference between `f1` and `f2`, but supposedly the rounding errors are larger than these differences:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp, fac, log

k = np.arange(1, 10001)
f1 = np.log(k).cumsum()
f2 = np.array([log(fac(ki)) for ki in k])
plt.plot(k, f1 - f2)
plt.show()
```

[image: f2-f1]

Computing everything in high precision, seems to indicate both are exactly the same:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpmath import mp, fac, log

mp.dps = 500  # default precission is about 15 digits, here 500 are used
k = range(1, 10001)

g = [log(ki) for ki in k]
f1 = []
s = 0
for gi in g:
    s += gi
    f1.append(s)
f2 = [log(fac(ki)) for ki in k]
f12 = [f1i - f2i for ki, f1i, f2i in zip(k, f1, f2)]

plt.plot(k, f12)
plt.show()
```

This is very slow, and finally displays a complete horizontal line, indicating that the differences are smaller than the smallest representable number. Mathematically it makes sense that both are exactly equal.

Comment: `plt.plot(k, np.log(scipy.special.factorial(k)))` for the second.

Comment: `scipy.special.factorial(k)` only seems to work up till `k=170`

Comment: Thank you! I'm really sorry but it says 'scipy' is not defined. Do I need to import something?

Comment: @JohanC Is that so? Is there a way to make it work up to 10,000?

Comment: I added the line import scipy and it's not working... Idk why this is happening

Comment: `import scipy.special`